# In html the radio button text clickable is not happening ? I had used the two list items in ul

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

See my problem is that i had written the code in angularjs with the using of ng-repeat for two times and based on some condition i had differentiated thatand one more important point is that i had all wriiten in the directive and calling it in the html view  . The radio button click is working fine when i press on the text the radio button is not working even though i had added the label with for and id in input .Please check the below fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajsy7/7/

controller :

```
     angular.module("myApp", [])
           .directive("myDirective", function () {
            return {
        restrict: 'EA',       
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            combo: '=combo'
        },
        template: '<ul ng-repeat="comboCollection in combo.comboCollections">'+'<li>'+
        '<label for={{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}>'+'</label>'+
        '<input type="radio" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" value="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" ng-show="comboCollection.havingSub" id={{comboCollection.comboItemCode}} ng-checked="true">'+
        '{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}'+
        '</li>' +'<li ng-repeat="substitute in combo.itemSubstitutes" ng-show="substitute.forItem==comboCollection.comboItemCode">'+
        '<label for="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}-{{substitute.subItemCode}}">'+'</label>'+
        '<input type="radio" id="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}-{{substitute.subItemCode}}" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}"  value="{{substitute.subItemName}}">'+'{{substitute.subItemName}}'+'</li>'+'</ul>'

    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'aaa';
    $scope.simple=function(){
        $scope.test='taheer';
    };
    $scope.combo = {
        "comboCollections": [
            {
                "comboItemCode": 1,
                "comboItemName": "CHICKEN BIRYANI",
                "comboQty": 1,
                "comboPrice": 450
            },
            {
                "comboItemCode": 12,
                "comboItemName": "BUTTERCHICKEN",
                "comboQty": 1,
                "comboPrice": 450,
                "havingSub":"Yes"
            },
            {
                "comboItemCode": 4,
                "comboItemName": "DIET COKE",
                "comboQty": 1,
                "comboPrice": 450,
                "havingSub":"Yes"
            }
        ],
        "itemSubstitutes": [
            {
                "subItemCode": 11,
                "subItemName": "NAAN",
                "subQuantity": 1,
                "subPrice": 450,
                "forItem": 12
            },
            {
                "subItemCode": 6,
                "subItemName": "FANTA",
                "subQuantity": 1,
                "subPrice": 450,
                "forItem": 4
            },
            {
                "subItemCode": 5,
                "subItemName": "PEPSI",
                "subQuantity": 1,
                "subPrice": 450,
                "forItem": 4
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

[a link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajsy7/7/)!

Comment: You have no text inside the label tag. `{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}` should be inside your label.

Comment: have to have text in label...it's not clickable because it's 0px wide. Pretty simple to find in browser console!!

Comment: tanq @jpmorin If i want to add the ng-click for the list item i need the $complile for dynamic binding or the directive whch i had written is enough ?

Comment: tanq @ charlietfi i am new to html and angular  that's why i am  getting  some  struggle .

Comment: This is not an angular problem, more of a misunderstanding of how the `label` tag is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not put text in the `label` tag and you forgot `"` around the `for` attribute.

Edit: added the closing `/` to the `input` tags.

**template:**

```
    '<ul ng-repeat="comboCollection in combo.comboCollections">'+
    '<li>'+
        '<input type="radio" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" value="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" id={{comboCollection.comboItemCode}} ng-show="comboCollection.havingSub" ng-checked="true" />'+
        '<label for="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}">{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}</label>'+
    '</li>' +
    '<li ng-repeat="substitute in combo.itemSubstitutes" ng-show="substitute.forItem==comboCollection.comboItemCode">'+
        '<input type="radio" id="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}-{{substitute.subItemCode}}" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" value="{{substitute.subItemName}}" />'+
        '<label for="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}-{{substitute.subItemCode}}">{{substitute.subItemName}}</label>'+
    '</li>'+
    '</ul>'
```

Or you can wrap your `radio` inside the `label` and not have to specify the `for` attribute.

**template:**

```
    '<ul ng-repeat="comboCollection in combo.comboCollections">'+
    '<li>'+
        '<label>'+
            '<input type="radio" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" value="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" id={{comboCollection.comboItemCode}} ng-checked="true" />'+
            '{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}'+
        '</label>'+
    '</li>' +
    '<li ng-repeat="substitute in combo.itemSubstitutes" ng-show="substitute.forItem==comboCollection.comboItemCode">'+
        '<label>'+
            '<input type="radio" id="{{comboCollection.comboItemCode}}-{{substitute.subItemCode}}" name="{{comboCollection.comboItemName}}" value="{{substitute.subItemName}}" />'+
            '{{substitute.subItemName}}'+
        '</label>'+
    '</li>'+
    '</ul>'
```